# Using method.invoke Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments

Tags: java

I am attempting to invoke a method and return the value; however, I get an IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments

here is the sample code:

```
public class MyObjAnnoParser {

  public void parse(Class clazz, Object obj) throws ClassNotFoundException, 
        IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, 
        InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException{

    WatchLogAnno wlAnno= method.getAnnotation(WatchLogAnno.class);

    Method[] methods = clazz.getMethods();

    for (Method method : methods) {

        if (method.isAnnotationPresent(WatchLogAnno.class)) {

            String info = wlAnno.parentClass(); 

            Class cls = Class.forName(info); 

            //error occurs here -- not sure what it means by wrong number 
            //the obj is wrapped as an Object array as can be seen....
            Object objVal= method.invoke(cls.newInstance(), new Object[]{obj});

            System.out.println(objVal);
        }
     }
  }

}
```

Annotation class:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD )
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface WatchLogAnno {
    String parentClass() default "";
}
```

MyObj Class:

```
public class MyObj {
    private String summary;

    @WatchLogAnno(parentClass = "com.stuff.MyObj")
    public String getSummary(){
        return summary;
    }

    public void setSummary(String summary){
        this.summary = summary;
    }
}
```

Test class that calls parser:

```
public class MyObjAnnoParserTest {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {

        MyObjAnnoParser parser = new MyObjAnnoParser ();

        parser.parse(Annotated.class);

        MyObj myObj = new MyObj();

        myObj.setSummary("Testing an entry for this piece");

        parser.parse(myObj.class, myObj ); 
    }
 }
```

So, as I listed above in the comments, when I get to the invoke.method call it throws the IllegalArgumentException....

I am sure it is a simple mistake...I appreciate any help...Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line

```
Object objVal= method.invoke(cls.newInstance(), new Object[]{obj});
```

you try to call a method with the signature

```
Object method(Object o)
```

but your clas has the signature

```
String getSummary()
```

therefore reflection cannot find any method.

Also you create a new object o your class instead of using the supplied one.

Try calling reflection with

```
Object objVal = method.invoke(obj, new Object[]{});
```

without any parameter.

Comment: right...so if I use method.invoke(cls.newInstance(), new Object[]{})  instead of method.invoke(cls.newInstance(), new Object[]{myObj}), the returned value from getSummary() is null because its not actually access in the instantiated class...

Answer (score 0):

```
package test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;



@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class datadriven_jnuit {


    private int var1;
    private int var2;
    public void datadriven_junit(int a, int b)
    {
    this.var1 = a;
    this.var2 = b;
    }

    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static List<Object []> data()
    {


        return Arrays.asList (new Object[][] { {543,11},{65,47}} );
    }

    @Test

    public void testcase()
    {
        System.out.println( var1);
        System.out.println(var2);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

The method

```
@WatchLogAnno(parentClass = "com.stuff.MyObj")
public String getSummary(){
    return summary;
}
```

doesn't take any parameters (except the implicit `this` object). However, when invoking the method, you pass one along:

```
method.invoke(cls.newInstance(), new Object[]{obj});
```

Either do

```
method.invoke(cls.newInstance(), new Object[0]);
```

or define the callee to take a parameter:

```
@WatchLogAnno(parentClass = "com.stuff.MyObj")
public String getSummary(Object mustBeDeclaredEvenIfNotUsed){
    return summary;
}
```

As a third possibility, [use reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getParameterTypes%28%29) to check, how many parameters the method-to-be-called expects, and adjust the parameters accordingly:

```
 // UNTESTED!

 final Class<?>[] expectedParams = method.getParameterTypes();
 Object[] actualValues;

 if (expectedParams.length == 0) actualValues = new Object[0];
 else if (expectedParams.length == 1) actualValues = new Object[] { obj };
 else
     throw new UnsupportedOperationException("callee has wrong method signature");
```

If you go this route, then checking, whether the declared argument type is compatible with the actual value might also be a good idea:

```
 if (!expectedParams[0].isAssignableFrom(obj))
     throw new UnsupportedOperationException("callee's declared parameter type does not match the argument value");
```

Comment: hmmm... so MyObj class contains a set value of summary. I understand now how I was misusing the invoke method, but still not sure how to acccess the getSummary() method.

Comment: well what I mean is the instantiated class MyObj myObj and the value set in summary from getSummary() method...not sure if I am making sense...

Comment: thanks...dirk... I had it backwards on the method.invoke... to get the value from getSummary() I had to do method.invoke(obj, new Object[]{});.... thanks again for both... it helps to be able to reflect these questions off someone else...